# Syncing (sharing) xampp mysql database over multiple machines on mac Sierra

Tags: mysql, xampp, dropbox

I want to sync (share) A MYSQL database over several computers.  My strategy here is to move the database to a DropBox directory so it can be used on multiple machines.  I have found a clear description of how to do this on Windows, but the location of the database in the XAMPP directory and the names and locations of the mysql configuration files (my.ini on Windows, my.cnf on mac) are different.  The config file directives are different enough that I couldn't get it to work on the mac simply by comparing the changes made in the Windows file.

I tried moving the MYSQL database and changing the my.cnf file as it made sense to me to direct the software to the new location and was unable to get it to work.  I also tried leaving the config files along and attempting to redirect xampp with a symlink in the directory where it looked for the database folder.  In neither case could I get xampp to fire up mysql.

I have had inconsistent success using symlinks with xampp, using them primarily to redirect xampp to a new php localhost directory.  In this case I couldn't get it to do this with mysql.

Does anyone know how to do this, i.e. which setting in the my.cnf file need to be redirected (I've tried about every variation I could think of) or how to get it to follow a smylink to the alternative directory?

Thanks in advance for any help.

--Kenoli

Answer (score 1):

if you are on a Local Area Network you can simply use one of your PCs as a mysql server and connect to the database using the local IP address. If not, I solved this using Hamachi, and using the Hamachi ip address of the pc you want to use as a server. I know this is not a direct response about the symlinks and DropBox, but it solves the problem.